# RequestDispatcher not forwarding to the new page

Tags: jsp

I have a list of links of ProductName, like this:

```
<a href='btnAction=productDetails&productId=IP16G'> IPhone </a'>
<a href='btnAction=productDetails&productID=SOPr'> Some other product </a> and so on ...
```

I have tried debugging and have found that `P` is not `null`, but `request.getRequestDispatcher("details.jsp")` is not forwarding to `details.jsp` page.

Below is the relevant code block:

```
if (action.equals("productDetails")) {

    try {

        String productId = request.getParameter("productId");

        ProductsRepository pRep  = new ProductsRepository();

        pRep.getProductById(productId);

        Products p = pRep.getProduct();

        request.setAttribute("Product", p);

        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("details.jsp");

        rd.forward(request, response);
```

Comment: Redirecting looks ok to me. Are you sure the code is being executed?

Comment: @f_puras: This is not redirecting. This is forwarding.

Comment: @f_purs: code executed. ok. i set line BreakPoint in details.jsp, but it don't run to it

Comment: where is the `details.jsp` placed, I mean what is the path to it like `/WEB-INF/jsp/details.jsp` or `/WEB-INF/details.jsp` or outside the WEB-INF folder?

Comment: Also I hope the code inside the `if` block is executed. How do you know it is being executed or not?

Comment: Any exceptions? Log information?

Comment: I'd bet on a bunch of `IllegalStateException`s in the server log.

Comment: @PrakashK : details.jsp in same paced with another page ( index.jsp ... ). Code inside the IF block is executed . but it isn't not forward to details.jsp

Comment: @Dave Newton : Thanks you ! I didn't se Log infomation . i had an error from tagLib in details.jsp.

Comment: Ps : thanks you all for reading my question ^^! <br/> My english is not verry well